# C++ How to handle different class in a template

Tags: c++, templates, typeid

Below code generate error for complaining No member named  `a` in `Cat` and No member named `b` in `Dog`

```
struct Dog{
    int a = 2;
};

struct Cat{
    int b = 3;
};

template <typename T>
void print( T* t){
    if (typeid(T) == typeid(Dog))
        cout << "Dog a "<<t->a<<endl;
    else if (typeid(T) == typeid(cat))
        cout <<" Cat b "<<t->b<<endl;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    // insert code here...
    Dog * p1 = new Dog();
    print(p1);
    
    Cat * p2 = new Cat();
    print(p2);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just write two non-template overloads of `print`, one taking `Cat*` and one taking `Dog*`. It doesn't make sense to try and use a template here.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Even better, make `friend operator<<()` overloads so you can just write `std::cout << p1`. See: https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/overloading-the-io-operators/

Comment: You could also replace the `if` condition with `if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, Dog>)`. But that should be your last resort. Overloading (especially if you use operator<<) is much more sensible here.

Comment: Also, your code have memory leaks...

Answer (score 3):

As others have pointed out, there are different ways to make it work.

This however, does not work because `print()` is not a function, but a function template. It's a blueprint for the concrete types. If you try to call `print(Dog)`, what compiler does is, substitutes `T` with `Dog`:

```
void print( Dog* t){
if (typeid(Dog) == typeid(Dog))
    cout << "Dog a "<<t->a<<endl;
else if (typeid(Dog) == typeid(cat))
    cout <<" Cat b "<<t->b<<endl;
}
```

Now, this would not compile for obvious reasons - `Dog` does not have the member `b`. The `else` branch is false, but this does not warrant to write code that does not compile there. (And by the way, you misspelled the class `Cat` there). Same for `Cat`s instantiation.